# How to count neighbouring cells in a numpy array using try-except?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, neighbours

I have a numpy array:

```
x = np.random.rand(4, 5)
```

**I would like to create an array showing how many neighbouring values are there for each value in the original array**. By neighbouring I mean:

```
example=np.array([[0,1,0,0,0],
                  [1,2,1,0,0],
                  [0,1,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0]])

plt.imshow(example)
```

[image]

The value at position `[1][1]` has 4 neighbours (the yellow square has 4 adjacent green cells).

A solution which works:

```
x = np.random.rand(4, 5)

mask = 4*np.ones(x.shape, dtype=int)

mask[0][:]=3
mask[-1][:]=3

for each in mask: each[0]=3
for each in mask: each[-1]=3

mask[0][0]=2
mask[0][-1]=2
mask[-1][0]=2
mask[-1][-1]=2
```

`mask` becomes:

```
array([[2, 3, 3, 3, 2],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [2, 3, 3, 3, 2]])
```

Now I try to create the same array with `try-except`:

```
x = np.random.rand(4, 5)

numofneighbours=[]

for index, each in enumerate(x):    
    row=[]
    for INDEX, EACH in enumerate(each):

        c=4
        try:ap[index+1][INDEX]
        except:c-=1

        try:ap[index][INDEX+1]
        except:c-=1

        try:ap[index-1][INDEX]
        except:c-=1

        try:ap[index][INDEX-1]   
        except:c-=1

        row.append(c)

    numofneighbours.append(row)
numofneighbours=np.asarray(numofneighbours)
```

Giving thre resulting `numofneighbours` array:

```
array([[4, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 2]])
```

Which is not equal to `mask`, as I expected it to be.

**What am I doing wrong here or how should I use try-except for the purpose described above?**

Comment: For the neighbours do you just count how many nieghbouring cells, or you sum their values?

Comment: Just the number of them (how many - not sum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that numpy allows negative indexing. `a[-1]` stands for the last value in `a` which is why the first numbers in your array are not decreased.

I think the first way you described is cleaner and faster than the try-except method and you should just use that.

Comment: Thank you, I believe your answer is right. I plan to use the try-except for something else as well, this was supposed to be a simplified question for a more complicated problem.

Answer (score 2):

Realised that `index-1` and `INDEX-1` indicies are still valid when `index` and `INDEX` are equal to 0, they just have the value `-1`, making it a valid array index even though the value they are refering to is not neighbouring the value referred to by `index` and `INDEX`. My fix is the following:

```
x = np.random.rand(4, 5)

numofneighbours=[]

for index, each in enumerate(x):    
    row=[]
    for INDEX, EACH in enumerate(each):

        c=4
        try:x[index+1][INDEX]
        except:c-=1

        try:x[index][INDEX+1]
        except:c-=1

        try:x[index-1][INDEX]
        except:c-=1
        if (index-1)<0: c-=1

        try:x[index][INDEX-1]
        except:c-=1
        if (INDEX-1)<0: c-=1

        row.append(c)

    numofneighbours.append(row)
numofneighbours=np.asarray(numofneighbours)
```

This gives:

```
array([[2, 3, 3, 3, 2],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [2, 3, 3, 3, 2]])
```